# Python like Slicing operation in c++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have following code, where 'Snap.JPG' is a RGB format type.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("./Snap.JPG")

img[:,:,:2] = 255

cv2.imshow("Img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want to convert this code into c++. What is the fastest way to implement `img[:,:,:2] = 255` part of the code? Channel splitting and merging is one of the options i know, but is there any smarter way to do slicing in c++?

Edit:
Apologies, i should have mentioned what i want in the output. I need a fading effect, because i wanted to overlay a drawing on top of it.

Comment: Can you describe what `img[:,:,:2]` does with an example?

Comment: I would assume it evaluates to an l-value expression.

Comment: Splitting and merging will definitely be sub-optimal due to copies involved. The compiler ought to be able to optimize a simple loop over all elements, where you overwrite just the first two parts of the `Vec3b`. And then maybe convert it derived class of `cv::ParallelLoopBody` so you can run it with `cv::parallel_for_`... or maybe these days a lambda will do as well.

Comment: @cigien, I guess it sets `img[i, j, k]` to `255` for all `i` and `j`, and `k = 0, 1`.

Comment: @cigien It creates a view to the original array that only contains the first two channels. And then you assign 255 to all the values in the first and second channel. Given the image is BGR (it's OpenCV), it means all the blue and green intensities of all the pixels in the image get set to 255.

Comment: @cigien, apologies for late reply! Yes as Evg suggested fade out B and G channels. It sort of gives face out effect to the image.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how to change pixels:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cv::Mat src_image = cv::imread("image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    if(!src_image.data) {
        std::cout << "Error: the image wasn't correctly loaded." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat image = src_image.clone();

    // We iterate over all pixels of the image
    for(int r = 0; r < image.rows; r++) {
        // We obtain a pointer to the beginning of row r
        cv::Vec3b* ptr = image.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(r);

        for(int c = 0; c < image.cols; c++) {
            ptr[c] = cv::Vec3b(255, 255, ptr[c][2]);
        }
    }

    cv::imshow("Inverted Image", image);
    cv::waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @Manuel's reply, it works quite well. but i could achieve the same result with faster speeds. I have added my code snippets inline your code.

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    clock_t start, end;

    cv::Mat src_image = cv::imread("Snap.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    if(!src_image.data) {
        std::cout << "Error: the image wasn't correctly loaded." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    /* 1st method */
    cv::Mat image = src_image.clone();

    start = clock();
    // We iterate over all pixels of the image
    for(int r = 0; r < image.rows; r++) {
        // We obtain a pointer to the beginning of row r
        cv::Vec3b* ptr = image.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(r);

        for(int c = 0; c < image.cols; c++) {
            ptr[c] = cv::Vec3b(255, 255, ptr[c][2]);
        }
    }
    end = clock();

    double time_taken = double(end - start) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    std::cout << "Time taken by 1st method : " << std::fixed << time_taken << std::setprecision(5);
    std::cout << " sec " << std::endl;

    /* 2nd Method */
    start = clock();
    src_image = src_image | cv::Scalar(255, 255, 0);
    end = clock();

    time_taken = double(end - start) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    std::cout << "Time taken by 2nd method : " << std::fixed << time_taken << std::setprecision(5);
    std::cout << " sec " << std::endl;

    bool isEqual = (sum(src_image != image) == cv::Scalar(0,0,0,0));
    if (isEqual)
    {
        std::cout << "\nIdentical Mats !" << std::endl;
    }

    cv::imshow("Inverted Image", image);
    cv::waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

output is following:

```
Time taken by 1st method : 0.001765 sec
Time taken by 2nd method : 0.00011 sec

Identical Mats !
```